# How do i do a index match split and concatenate multipul IDs in a cell in google sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hey all please help me i need your help with something i been breaking my head on

basically lets say in google sheets i have a list of products and each product has an ID

when making me sheet i have boxes that contain more than 1 product so in a single cell there is for this case 3 different ID codes displayed like this (eg:  `087345-080046-083823`)

i need to some how in the column in another sheet state what the products are for (eg:Shirts-shoes-shorts) so whet im looking for that i cant find anywhere is a formula like

```
=Index(split()match()concatenate())
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do but perhaps this idea will help: You can include wild cards in your lookup value, like `MATCH("*shoes*",A:A,False)`

Comment: try to use split and vlookup

Comment: Show your data sample and your desired output.

Comment: In excel can be solved with user function too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula solution work in Excel sheet for the Office 365 version due to the using of TEXTJOIN function.

In `E2`, enter array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) :

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",1,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A10,0&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(D2,"-","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),0)),B2:B10,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Bonus points if you can get the product names in the same order as the product number!  Regardless nice answer.

Comment: this works awesomely i just needed to change my layout a bit but its working after i did. like you said though the ID number on occasion does not match the product but for my purpose as just a listing of products its fine. but i will try the others as well to see if that could be doen.

Answer (score 0):

You said that in google sheets you have a list of products, so below is formula in google sheet. Assumption data in E1:E2 and master in A2:B4, then:

```
= arrayformula
  ( substitute
    ( transpose
      ( query
        ( transpose
          ( vlookup
            ( split ("'" & substitute(E1:E2,"-","-'"),"-",true,true) ,
              ProdMaster!A2:B4,2,false
            ) & "-"
          ),"Select *",1000
        ) & "%"
      ),"-%",""
    )
  )
```